# IIS Server Service Unavailable 503 MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis, web-deployment

I tried to deployee my application in one server (windows 7 ultimate 32 bit) and share the application via network to access in other systems.

1. I installed IIS Server via windows feature (IIS and Windows Process Activation Service)
2. Open IIS Server and right click the Sites Add new web site.
3. I m given site name as Raja and Select Application pool (ASP.NET v4.0) then choose physical path as D:\Uma (Root Folder).
4. Assign IP address as 192.168.1.249 then port number 81 and hostname as localhost and click ok.
5. then i have added all files in D:\uma folder with webconfig file.

(this web site is running perfectly in cloud server window Server 2008 i have used same webconfig file)

My server, web site and application pool all are running but when i browse it show Service Unavailable Http Error 503

Shall i missed any steps please help me out last two days i have tried. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any entries in the event log?

Comment: i dont know how to check event log can you tell me please

Comment: Open start menu, type "event", click "event viewer/view event logs", when event viewer opens choose "custom views" then "Administrative events". Look for anything that has IIS as the event source.

Comment: Yes lot of warning and error is there is showing Source as Browser

Comment: In Custom Views --> Administrative Events

Comment: That 'browser' is unrelated to your problem. Look for events with a source of IIS

Comment: There is no event in IIS (Event Viewer --> Applications and Services --> Microdoft --> Windows --> IIS --> IIS Diagnostics Channel) No events is there

Comment: Are you sure that you are including port number in url while browsing your website since you are using non standard http port?

Comment: Ya localhost:81 and i tried to click browse from iis server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to fix that:

```
start-service w3svc
remove-item -recurse -force C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\*
stop-service -force WAS
```

Probably your windows was updated recently.